# How to have 2 authentication schemes / functions working in an Oracle Apex app

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex

I have an app where I have 2 tables for users, one for the employees, one for the clients, as you can see on the model below

[image: model]

So, I have a package (SECAPP) with a hash_pwd function, and 2 authenticate function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SECAPP AS
-->>--------------------------------------------------------------------
 FUNCTION hash_pwd (
  p_username IN VARCHAR2,
  p_password IN VARCHAR2
 ) RETURN VARCHAR2;
--<<--------------------------------------------------------------------

-->>--------------------------------------------------------------------
 FUNCTION authenticate_clients(
  p_username IN VARCHAR2,
  p_password IN VARCHAR2
 ) RETURN BOOLEAN;
--<<--------------------------------------------------------------------

-->>--------------------------------------------------------------------
 FUNCTION authenticate_employes(
  p_username IN VARCHAR2,
  p_password IN VARCHAR2
 ) RETURN BOOLEAN;
--<<--------------------------------------------------------------------
END SECAPP;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SECAPP IS

-->>--------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION hash_pwd(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
    l_password VARCHAR2(4000);
    l_salt VARCHAR2(4000) := 'mysalt';
BEGIN
    l_password := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5
    (input_string => p_password || SUBSTR(l_salt,10,13) || p_username || SUBSTR(l_salt, 4, 10)));
    RETURN l_password;
END hash_pwd;
--<<--------------------------------------------------------------------

-->>--------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION authenticate_clients (p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password in VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
as
L_COUNT number(1) := 0;
begin

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM CLIENTS
where upper(email) = upper(p_username)
AND pwd = hash_pwd(p_username, p_password);

RETURN (l_count > 0);
END authenticate_clients;
--<<--------------------------------------------------------------------

-->>--------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION authenticate_employes (p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS 
l_count NUMBER(1) := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM EMPLOYES
WHERE UPPER(email) = UPPER(p_username)
AND pwd = hash_pwd(p_username, p_password);

RETURN (l_count > 0);
END authenticate_employes;
--<<--------------------------------------------------------------------
END SECAPP;
/
```

I would like to have 2 logins portal

the original login page from Apex for the client, and an additional Employees login page that i could copy based on the original.

I've added the 2 authenticate functions in my authenticate schemes

In the Login Page process, there's this function `apex_authentication.login(p_username => :P9999_USERNAME, p_password => :P000_PASSSWORD);`

I tried changing it for `secapp.authenticate_employees(p_username => ....)`. But it doesn't seems to work, it only works when I keep the original apex function and making my authenticate_employees the current scheme.

How could I achieve 2 authenticate function ?

NB : I dont want to merge my employees and clients table, since they have different data.

Let me know if you need more informations, as it has been a while since I posted on SO.

Thanks in advance

Thomas

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks Koen Lostrie for the solution, heres my function that check the PAGE_ID and execute either one code of the two authenticate functions

```
FUNCTION authenticate_wrapper(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password in VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
l_count NUMBER(1) := 0;
l_app_page_id VARCHAR2(5) := NV('APP_PAGE_ID');
l_result BOOLEAN := false;
BEGIN

IF (l_app_page_id = '9998') THEN 
l_result := authenticate_clients(p_username => p_username, p_password => p_password);
END IF;
IF (l_app_page_id = '9999') THEN
l_result := authenticate_employes(p_username => p_username, p_password => p_password);
END IF;
RETURN l_result;
END authenticate_wrapper;
```

or.. with the code of the 2 functions directly in it :

```
FUNCTION authenticate_wrapper(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password in VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
l_count NUMBER(1) := 0;
l_app_page_id VARCHAR2(5) := NV('APP_PAGE_ID');
BEGIN

IF (l_app_page_id = '9998') THEN 
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM clients
where upper(email) = upper(p_username)
AND pwd = hash_pwd(p_username, p_password);

RETURN (l_count > 0);
END IF;
IF (l_app_page_id = '9999') THEN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM EMPLOYES
WHERE UPPER(email) = UPPER(p_username)
AND pwd = hash_pwd(p_username, p_password);

RETURN (l_count > 0);
END IF;
END authenticate_wrapper;
```

Comment: Here is an idea: create a login app for employees and another login app for customers. Use those 2 apps only to manage the authentication and put the actual functionality in a 3rd app. Then you only need 1 auth scheme per app

Comment: Another option would be to use a single authentication scheme with a wrapper function around it that determines base on the login page number what authentication function to invoke (employees or clients)

Comment: It's really interesting, thanks for the tip. However this is a school project and I'm not sure if having 3 apps for the project is allowed. I was thinking about merging my two authenticates function and trying to determine if the user comes from the employees or the clients table !

Comment: I've never tried working with the login page number in a PL/SQL function, would you be able to give me a hint on how to do it ? Thanks !

Comment: use the "V" or "NV" function - here are the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/understanding-substitution-strings.htm#GUID-D1155681-0C6B-4C00-B51F-2398E71ACCB3)

Comment: i'll try to do something, i'll post an update with my function if I can't make it work properly, thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: the wrapper is working perfectly, thanks a lot ! would you like to post your solution so I can mark it as the answer ? .-)

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Thanks Koen Lostrie for the solution, heres my function that check the PAGE_ID and execute either one code of the two authenticate functions

```
FUNCTION authenticate_wrapper(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password in VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
l_count NUMBER(1) := 0;
l_app_page_id VARCHAR2(5) := NV('APP_PAGE_ID');
l_result BOOLEAN := false;
BEGIN

IF (l_app_page_id = '9998') THEN 
l_result := authenticate_clients(p_username => p_username, p_password => p_password);
END IF;
IF (l_app_page_id = '9999') THEN
l_result := authenticate_employes(p_username => p_username, p_password => p_password);
END IF;
RETURN l_result;
END authenticate_wrapper;
```

or.. with the code of the 2 functions directly in it :

```
FUNCTION authenticate_wrapper(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password in VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
l_count NUMBER(1) := 0;
l_app_page_id VARCHAR2(5) := NV('APP_PAGE_ID');
BEGIN

IF (l_app_page_id = '9998') THEN 
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM clients
where upper(email) = upper(p_username)
AND pwd = hash_pwd(p_username, p_password);

RETURN (l_count > 0);
END IF;
IF (l_app_page_id = '9999') THEN
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM EMPLOYES
WHERE UPPER(email) = UPPER(p_username)
AND pwd = hash_pwd(p_username, p_password);

RETURN (l_count > 0);
END IF;
END authenticate_wrapper;
```